# Spring Security XML Error - cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'csrf'

Tags: xml, spring-security, xsd, schema, csrf

I am using Spring Security in my web application project. I want to enable csrf protection in my Spring application. 
My application-context-security.xml is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                         http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/> 

    <http disable-url-rewriting="true" auto-config="false" access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint">
        <intercept-url pattern="/" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_check" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
        <intercept-url pattern="/j_spring_security_logout" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY, IS_AUTHENTICATED_REMEMBERED"/>
<!-- Enable CSRF protection -->
        <csrf />
    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>         
    </http>
<!-- Remaining information -->
</beans:beans>
```

I am using Spring 3.0.5 jars for my project.

While running though, I get the following error

```
SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener 
instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException:
 nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
Invalid content was found starting with element 'csrf'. 
One of 
'{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":intercept-url,
 "http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":access-denied-handler, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":form-login, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":openid-login, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":x509, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":http-basic, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":logout, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":session-management, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":remember-me, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":anonymous, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":port-mappings, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":custom-filter, 
"http://www.springframework.org/schema/security":request-cache}' 
is expected.
```

I tried searching for this error on google. I found a couple of similar places, but they both said the error was due to some change in Spring 3.2+. However, in my case I am using Spring 3.0.5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **csrf** shortcut of spring security was introduced with the version 3.2.0 (see [blogpost](http://spring.io/blog/2013/08/21/spring-security-3-2-0-rc1-highlights-csrf-protection/))

Maybe you should considerate updating your used spring version

Comment: As it turns out, in my case I need CSRF protection in only a few forms. So I ended up not using this csrf tag in the xml. Still thanks for the reply. Marking your answer as correct as you were the first to answer.

Answer (score 4):

Got the same error after updating from 
spring 3.2.5 to 4.2.0
spring security 3.1.4 to 4.0.2

I had to change the schema location from
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
to
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi.xsd
          http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">
```

In your case, the <csrf> element does not exist in spring 3.0.5.
So updating to at least 3.2 would be the solution.

Comment: Yes that appears to be the case. In my case though, I don't need CSRF protection on every single form so I decided to manually put tokens in my Form and validate them. Thanks for the reply.